# How to print stack trace with reference to typescript source in Nest.js

Tags: stack-trace, nestjs, console.log

I am developing a Nest.js server and would like to be able to print useful stack trace in console (e.g. console.log). By default, it returns a reference to the line number in the compiled sources (.js). This is not useful for debugging as it's missing the reference to the line number in the original source files (.ts)

Here is my tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "_baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

The .map files are generated in the dist folder as well, though it seems to be of no use when checking stack traces in the console.

Comment: Do you have source maps enabled in your tsconfig?

Comment: Yes, I have updated my question with the tsconfig content

Comment: So, after testing in my own server, I only get one line to say `ts` and that's because the server is webpacked via the `ng` compiler. Everything is in `js` files as expected cause you're running JavaScript. This is the default behavior, but it looks like [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40175651/9576186) shows a way to get ts lines in the stack trace instead

Comment: Thank you! It works, just by adding `source-map-support` to the project, now it outputs the line number from the `ts` file

Answer (score 46, accepted):

For visibility purposes: adding the [source-map-support](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-support) NPM package allows for tracing typescript files in the stack trace.

It can be added on the command line with `node -r source-map-support/register fileToRun.js` or programatically with

```js
import * as sourceMapSupport from 'source-map-support';
sourceMapSupport.install();
```

OR

```js
import { install } from 'source-map-support';
install();
```

OR with ES6 modules

```js
import 'source-map-support/register';
```

#### Update

From [the node-source-map-support repository](https://github.com/evanw/node-source-map-support?tab=readme-ov-file#node-12120):

> Node >=12.12.0
>
> This package is no longer required as Node 12.12.0 introduced the --enable-source-maps flag. (unless you're using the vm module, as --enable-source-maps does not work with vm.runInThisContext).

Comment: Do I have to add this to every file separately? Or is there a way to do this globally for my whole NestJS project?

Comment: You should just need to add it to your `main.ts` Or to the command line as mentioned.

Comment: in typescript dont forget to `npm i --save-dev @types/source-map-support`

Answer (score 5):

I was only able to get this working if I also added a

> webpack.config.js

file into the root directory of the NestJS project with following content:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = function(options) {
  return {
    ...options,
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  }
}
```

With this file in place it is possible to configure Webpack to your needs when transpilling your NestJS sources to main.js.

In main.ts I added following lines as described in answer above:

```
import * as sourceMapSupport from 'source-map-support';
sourceMapSupport.install();
```

Voila its working and exact Typescript files plus line numbers are displayed in console stack trace.

Comment: Could you provide some context about the configuration (e.g., package.json, tsconfig.json) that you are using?

Comment: Nothing special there: Just add "sourceMap": true to tsconfig.json. package.json remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of configuring hot reload according to the [nestjs doc](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/hot-reload).
In my case, I used the way of leveraging the nest cli.

Steps:

1. `npm i source-map-support`, `npm i -D @types/source-map-support`
2. Add `import "source-map-support/register"` to your `main.ts`
3. Add `devtool: 'inline-source-map'` to your `webpack-hmr.config.js`

And voila! It works as expected.

Here's my `webpack-hmr.config.js` after finishing Step 3:
(same as in the docs but added one line)

```js
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const { RunScriptWebpackPlugin } = require('run-script-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = function (options, webpack) {
  return {
    ...options,
    entry: ['webpack/hot/poll?100', options.entry],
    externals: [
      nodeExternals({
        allowlist: ['webpack/hot/poll?100'],
      }),
    ],
    plugins: [
      ...options.plugins,
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin({
        paths: [/\.js$/, /\.d\.ts$/],
      }),
      new RunScriptWebpackPlugin({
        name: options.output.filename,
        autoRestart: false,
      }),
    ],
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  };
};
```

If you are configuring the hot module reload without the nest cli, add the line to `webpack.config.js` instead of `webpack-hmr.config.js` in the Step 3.

Comment: Nice! Will definetely give it a try. Didn't know that HMR is also available for Nest.js projects. I thought its more a thing for frontend development. I configured HMR for Angular once and it was kind of pain.