# develop with nestJS start:dev, or start:debug how to have those error or stack trace mapped to Typescript file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, debugging, nestjs

I'm expecting **NestJs** a typescript nodejs backend framework would be able to map to the typescript file whenever there is an error occurred, when using the default command `npm run start:dev` or `npm run start:debug`

From what I experienced, when there is an error output, the stack trace is referred to javascript counterpart. I feel that is kinda defeating the purpose.

Does anyone have an idea how to configure the project to run in 'watch & automatically compile' mode; when there is stack trace or error occurs, to have it mapped to the Typescript file instead?

[image: The sample of NestJS output where is there an error.]

### Update

Eventually I changed the code to use `source-map-support` to print the stack-trace with reference to typescript

[How to print stack trace with reference to typescript source in Nest.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59000552/how-to-print-stack-trace-with-)
reference-to-typescript-source-in-nest-js (highlighted in the comment by Jay)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print stack trace with reference to typescript source in Nest.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59000552/how-to-print-stack-trace-with-reference-to-typescript-source-in-nest-js)

Comment: yes, it does. That works.